# Where does Maimonides write that Muslims may pray in a synagogue?

Tags: tefilla, gentiles, rambam, synagogue, islam

Regarding [the Muslims who were praying](http://www.breakingisraelnews.com/77514/muslims-praying-israeli-airport-synagogue-kick-religious-controversy/) in a Synagogue, I read that Rambam ruled that it was permissible for Muslims to pray in a Synagogue - I haven't been able to find a source for this, does someone have a reference to it?

Note: I'm specifically asking about Islamic prayers, not Jewish prayers.

Comment: I suspect you are getting confused with his view on Jews praying in mosques.

Comment: @mevaqesh I am basing it off the article linked where it says: "One comment on Cohen’s Facebook post noted that this precise situation was discussed by Maimonides, the foremost Torah authority of the 12th century, whose rulings are still used as the basis for much of Jewish law. Maimonides ruled that it is permitted for Muslims to pray in a synagogue."

Comment: Perhaps that individual was mistaken. Have you tried contacting him?

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps the confusion stems from his responsum about Karaites in the Synagogue.